# Dynamic components and field sets?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having difficulty getting my dynamic component to work with a field a set. I want a set of input fields for a related object to the controller. The input fields aren't getting rendered. What am I doing wrong?

```
public Mycustom__c NewRecord;

public Mycustom__c getNewRecord(){
        Mycustom__c a= new Mycustom__c();
        return a;
    }

  public Component.Apex.PageBlockSection getNewSection()
    {
        Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbs = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
        pbs.columns = 1;
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : SObjectType.Mycustom__c.FieldSets.myFieldSet.getFields() )
        {
            Component.Apex.InputField inputField = new Component.Apex.InputField();
            inputField.expressions.value = '{!getNewRecord.' + fsm.getFieldPath() + '}';  // <---- I think this might be wrong?
            Component.Apex.OutputLabel theNameLabel = new Component.Apex.OutputLabel();
            theNameLabel.value = fsm.getLabel();
            system.debug(fsm);// prints out the name of the field in the field set

        }
        return pbs;  
    }


        <apex:pageBlock title="My Dynamic Component to create a new record">
            <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!getNewSection}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected code .

There were multiple issues and below code is working in my Dev org .One thing to note is I was playing with Account Object and created a sample fielset named test2

```
public class TestDynamicComponent{

 public Account NewRecord;

 public Account getNewRecord(){
    Account a= new Account ();
    return a;
 }

 public Component.Apex.PageBlockSection getNewSection(){
    Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbs = new   Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
    pbs.columns = 1;
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.test2.getFields() ){
        Component.Apex.InputField inputField = new Component.Apex.InputField();
        inputField.expressions.value = '{!NewRecord.' + fsm.getFieldPath() + '}';  // <---- observe the correction here
        Component.Apex.OutputLabel theNameLabel = new Component.Apex.OutputLabel();
        theNameLabel.value = fsm.getLabel();
        system.debug(fsm);// prints out the name of the field in the field set
        pbs.childComponents.add(inputField);

     }
     return pbs;  
 }

}
```

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="TestDynamicComponent">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
     <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!NewSection}"/>
   </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
```

Test screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith. The big change was the `pbs.childComponents.add(inputField);` line. That's new to me, and must've missed that in the documentation.

Comment: please mark as answered if that helps